# SQL Join same tables on datetime?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

**Data**

```
 id |   name |         ReadingDateTime | RID |           RName |     Value
173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-30 13:43:31.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12444,355
173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-31 12:44:29.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12452,486
173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-31 15:14:27.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12456,518
173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-31 17:14:34.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12459,294
...
```

**Query**

```
SELECT SRA2.Value-SRA.Value AS Diff, SRA.*
FROM Summary_Reading_All SRA
INNER JOIN Summary_Reading_All SRA2 ON SRA2.ReadingDateTime = SRA.ReadingDateTime
WHERE SRA.ReadingTypeId = 15
AND SRA.DeviceId = 173
ORDER BY SRA.ReadingDateTime
```

**Output**

```
Diff       |  id |   name |         ReadingDateTime | RID |           RName |     Value
0          | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
-5978,216  | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
-7807,397  | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
-12414,146 | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
11042,679  | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
-11580,143 | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
-12414,146 | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-27 14:06:39.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12414,146
(7 times)
Diff | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-30 13:43:31.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12444,355
(7 times)
Diff | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-31 12:44:29.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12452,486
(7 times)
Diff | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-31 15:14:27.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12456,518
(7 times)
Diff | 173 | OLİMPA | 2013-12-31 17:14:34.000 | 15  | Aktif Endeks T1 | 12459,294
```

I want to join same table and get difference of value fields. When I execute above code, then repeat each record 7 times. Why records are repeat 7 times, datetime field is uniqe.

Any Advice, Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to TheConstructors answer....

```
SELECT SRA2.Value-SRA.Value AS Diff, SRA.*
FROM Summary_Reading_All SRA
INNER JOIN Summary_Reading_All SRA2 ON SRA2.ReadingDateTime = SRA.ReadingDateTime
AND SRA.ReadingTypeId = SRA2.ReadingTypeId
AND SRA.DeviceId = SRA2.DeviceId
WHERE SRA.ReadingTypeId = 15
AND SRA.DeviceId = 173
ORDER BY SRA.ReadingDateTime
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot... I understand why repeat 7 times. First table is filtered by deviceId and ReadingTypeId, but second table not.

Comment: Second question: How can I get difference of value fields? I want to get `SRA.Value[1] - SRA.Value[0]` my code is wrong to get it.

Comment: How do you define get SRA.Value[1] - SRA.Value[0] ? Give an example.

Answer (score 0):

If `ReadingDateTime` is unique, you should only get one line where `Diff` is 0, as only the line itself could fullfill the `SRA2.ReadingDateTime = SRA.ReadingDateTime` part of the query.

Currently your `WHERE` condition only applies to SRA, but not SRA2. To get meaningfull results I guess you need to find a way to not match the line with itself; maybe by selecting a different deviceId in SRA2 or checking that the primary key is different between SRA and SRA2.